Number of conjugacy classes in each coset of a semidirect product is the same.
Let us consider a semidirect product $X=G \rtimes \langle\sigma\rangle$, where $\langle\sigma\rangle$ acts on $G$ via some automorphism. Assume all groups are finite and that $\sigma$ has order $b$.
If $g\sigma^{k}$  is a generic element of $X$, for $0<k<b$, then its $X$-conjugacy class is contained in $G\sigma^k$. Therefore, $G\sigma^k$ is the union of a certain number, say $n$, of $X$-conjugacy classes. How can I show that this number does not depend on $k$, i.e. that each coset $G\sigma^k$ contains the same number $n$ of conjugacy classes?
I am grateful for any hint.

I do not  believe that this is true.
Take $G:=\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^2=c^2=abc=1 \rangle$, the elementary group of order $4$.
Let $\sigma$ of order $6$ act on $G$ via $\sigma:a\mapsto b\mapsto c\mapsto a$.
Consider the cosets $G\sigma^2$ and $G\sigma^3$.
We have that $G\sigma^2=\{\sigma^2, a\sigma^2, b\sigma^2, c\sigma^2\}$. As the centraliser of $\sigma^2$ in $X$ is just $\langle\sigma\rangle$ this coset consists of a singke $X$-class.
We have that $G\sigma^3=\{\sigma^3,a\sigma^3,b\sigma^3,c\sigma^3\}$. As the centraliser of $\sigma^3$ in $X$ is $X$ this coset can't be a single $X$-class. (In fact it is easily checked to be the union of two $X$-classes.)

Thank you, I thought that this fact, which holds in the setting I am working with, was true in general. Many thanks.
